# Bootstrap 3 container with justify-content: space-between not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am trying to apply flex to bootstrap 3 container and found strange behaviour of child elements Here is the code.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="child">One</div>
   <div class="child">Two</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

(see example on jsfiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsenii/147nkw4z/))

I cannot find out what's the problem with the space-between.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: what browser are you using and what's the problem?

Comment: To understand as a beginner about flex - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-ultimate-guide-to-flexbox-learning-through-examples-8c90248d4676

Comment: @AakashThakur I found this bug and tried to understand the strange behaviour of flex here

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1400 I found this problem in chrome and FF, so I was pretty sure that it is not about browsers

Comment: @arjun I've already know all of this stuff, but if you will look at the justify-content and all different variants, you will find that the behaviour I wrote is different from the standard flex behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining Bootstrap 3 with Flexbox is not recommended.

That said, Bootstraps `container` class also uses both the pseudo elements, hence they will participate in the flex container being flex items, and here one can see them when giving them a small width/height and background color.

And as you can see, the `justify-content: space-between;` work as it is supposed to.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container::before, .container::after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">One</div>
  <div class="child">Two</div>
</div>
```

---

One workaround would be a wrapper

```css
.container .flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child">One</div>
    <div class="child">Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I'm finally understand what's the problem with it! I know that it is better to avoid combining bootstrap and flex, but I found this strange behaviour and tried to understand this feature.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that you're using a classname from bootstrap `.container` you're attempting to change the style. Just use a id instead of the classname container.

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="child">One</div>
  <div class="child">Two</div>
</div>
```